# Как добавить циклом элементы и вывести их?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human a1 = new Human("Михаил", true, 21);
        Human a2 = new Human("Олег", true, 22);
        Human a3 = new Human("Евгений", true, 23);
        Human a4 = new Human("Катя", false, 21);
        Human a5 = new Human("Игорь", true,22, a1.father, a4.mother);
        Human a6 = new Human("Аня", false, 30, a1.father,a4.mother);
        Human a7 = new Human("Светлана", false,22, a6.father,a6.mother);
        Human a8 = new Human("Дмитрий", true,40, a1.father, a6.mother);
        Human a9 = new Human("Павел", true, 33, a2.father, a7.mother);
        System.out.println(a1);
        System.out.println(a2);
        System.out.println(a3);
        System.out.println(a4);
        System.out.println(a5);
        System.out.println(a6);
        System.out.println(a7);
        System.out.println(a8);
        System.out.println(a9);


    }

    public static class Human {
        String name;
        int age;
        boolean sex;
        Human father;
        Human mother;

        public Human(String name, boolean sex, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.sex = sex;
        }

        public Human(String name, boolean sex, int age, Human father, Human mother) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.sex = sex;
            this.father = father;
            this.mother = mother;
        }

        public String toString() {
            String text = "";
            text += "Имя: " + this.name;
            text += ", пол: " + (this.sex ? "мужской" : "женский");
            text += ", возраст: " + this.age;

            if (this.father != null) {
                text += ", отец: " + this.father.name;
            }

            if (this.mother != null) {
                text += ", мать: " + this.mother.name;
            }

            return text;
        }
    }
```

Можно как то упростить и не писать 9 раз принт?

Comment: `List<Human> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add(new Human(...)); ...`

Comment: List<Human> list = Arrays.asList(new Human(..), new Human(..), ..);
list.foreach(human -> println(human));
или
Arrays.asList(new Human(...), new Human(..), ...).foreach(human -> println(human));
Как то так можно, правда в синтаксисе мог наврать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно упростить, использовав `коллекции`.
Пример:

```java
List<Human> humansCollection = new ArrayList();
humansCollection.add(a1);
//...
   for(Human a : humansCollection){ // Это цикл foreach
      System.out.println(a);
   }
```

Comment: Это получается нужно 9 раз add прописать чтоб создать коллекцию?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко не обязательно - можно написать `List<Human> humansCollection = List.of(new Human(...), new Human(...), new Human(...));` `List.of(...)` возвратит `ArrayList`, содержащий перечисленные элементы.

Comment: да это жесть) все это заново переписывать в коллекцию, легче 9 раз принт написать. Или я чего не понял. Правильно я понимаю, что в скобки с тремя точками мне нужно вручную заполнять все эти поля конструктора?

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко кстати, можно сделать с помощью простого массива, если количество элементов заранее известно. Его тоже можно через foreach прогнать. Да, но можно заранее создать эти объекты и просто передать в List.of

Comment: да, надо добавить до 9 элемента